# object disappears after move in flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

I am trying to prepare a simple animation of photos in flex. I got most of it done but when ever i do the following

```
<mx:Sequence id="bird" target="{birdImage}">
    <mx:Move xFrom="-100" yFrom="-100" xTo="100" yTo="100" duration="700" effectEnd="{bird2.play()}" easingFunction="mx.effects.easing.Quadratic.easeIn" />
</mx:Sequence>
```

The problem is that after the move before the next part starts the image disappears. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar trouble with moving two panels in a Hbox. The solution was to set the container's autoLayout property to false just before the effect starts.
If you are in a similar situation hope it helps.

Bye!